# Is a binary or sequential/linear search more efficient when searching a sorted linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, binary-search, performance, linear-search

I need to write a program that searches through a previously sorted linked list and I'm not sure which search would be more efficient.

Comment: If you want to take advantage of a sorted list, a better option is to have an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

All traversals of linked lists are in order, so a linear search is the best you can do, with an average case linear in the number of elements. If there are going to be lots of searches and you still need a linked list (instead of a random-access structure such as an array), consider a skip list, which lets you skip forward until you get near the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

Linear search would be more efficient, and here's why.

In order to get to the kth location in a doubly linked list of size *n*, you have to iterate over at most n/2 elements.

If you were to apply binary search on top of that, then you'd wind up having to go down *k* elements every time, plus the work to perform a binary search.

O(n + log(n)) = O(n), which is equivalent to the performance of a linear search.

Answer (score 0):

If your comparisons are cheap, the other answers are correct that linear and binary search are mostly equivalent (binary search has slightly higher expected number of node traversals, though the big-O is the same, `O(n)` traversals).

But this assumes that comparisons are a negligible cost relative to traversals. And that's not always a good assumption. If your comparisons are expensive, then binary search is still worth it, because binary search remains `O(log n)` on number of comparisons, while linear search is `O(n)`. For example, if your comparison operation is something ridiculously expensive (say, the MD5 hash of file data, and you didn't cache it with the file names for whatever reason), and you've got a 1000 element list, linear search means you're, on average, computing the MD5 hash of 500 files (in this case, you could probably reduce it a bit by choosing the end to start from based on whether the MD5 you're searching for begins with `0-7` or `8-f`, but even so, it's `O(n)` comparisons divided by a constant factor). Binary search means at most 10 (or 11, can't be bothered with off-by-one errors) file reads and MD5 computations. If the files are large enough, that's the difference between taking ~1 second to run and taking ~50 seconds.